# Nested flexbox not expanding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a dual column layout where the second column is also a grid with two cells inside of it. However the two cells in the nested grid are not expanding to fill their container.

How I'd like it:
[image: How I'd like it]

How it is:
[image: How it is]

When I set `.header-cell3and4` to have `flex: 1` instead of `display: flex` it messes up the positioning of my images inside the cell.

```
.header-grid1 { display: flex; }
.header-cell1 { flex: 0 0 66.6666%; }
.header-cell2 { flex: 0 0 33.3333%; }
.header-grid2 { display: flex; flex-flow: column; align-self: flex-start; text-align: center; }
.header-cell3and4 { display: flex; justify-content: center; }


<div id="header">
    <div class="header-Grid1">
        <div class="header-cell1">
            <img src="image.png">
        </div>

        <div class="header-cell2">
            <div class="header-grid2">
                <div class="header-cell3">
                    <img src="image.png" alt="text"><div class="flexcenter"><a href="link">text</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="header-cell4">
                    <img src="image.png" alt="text"><div class="flexcenter"><a href="link">text</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem was, that you didn't tell `header-cell4` to grow. You can do that with the flex-shortcut: `flex: 1 0 auto` (whereas the first value is `flex-grow`, the second value is `flex-shrink` and the third value is `flex-basis`).

If you want to learn more about flexbox, I recommend the [css-tricks flexbox guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Here is the working code:

CSS

```
.header-grid1 {
    display: flex;
}
.header-cell1 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 66.666%;
}
.header-cell2 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 33.333%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-cell3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.header-cell4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="header-grid1">
        <div class="header-cell1">
            <img src="image.png">
        </div>
        <div class="header-cell2">
            <div class="header-cell3">
                <img src="image.png" alt="text">
                <div class="flexcenter">
                    <a href="link">text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-cell4">
                <img src="image.png" alt="text">
                <div class="flexcenter">
                    <a href="link">text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gryLby6/2/

And please next time you post, give us your actually working CSS code, and not stuff like `.header-cell3and4`. It took me some time just to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying but no that does not fix it. I have added the flex: 1 property to header-cell4 in the code.

Comment: You need to use the whole code I posted, the top sentece just explained why it didn't work.

Comment: Yes but you've set a fixed height in your code which I am trying to avoid, and also that layout is not what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: The height was only for demonstration purposes, sorry. I removed it and the background colors. Check out the JSFiddle now. (PS: I left the background-color in the fiddle, so you might want to use the code here)